# Insert a value corresponding to the value of a propensity score matched person in data set

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, data-manipulation, propensity-score-matching

I have two groups (EG and CG) which were propensity score matched. My first data frame df_1 shows the corresponding pairs of participants.

```
df_1 <- read.table(text="
         ID_EG     ID_CG
         800289    823516
         800674    820870
         811434    800796
         838623    800958
         801208    836587
         801299    855510", header=TRUE)
```

Moreover, I have a data frame (in long format; i.e., every row is a measurement point) that includes only participants from the EG. This data frame also includes a variable indicating the age at timepoint 1 and a variable indicating the age group into which I selected the participants.

```
df_2 <- read.table(text="
        ID            age_T1      age_group
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young        
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800674        40          middle
        800674        40          middle
        800674        40          middle
        800674        40          middle
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        838623        36          middle
        838623        36          middle
        838623        36          middle
        838623        36          middle
        838623        36          middle
        801208        21          young
        801208        21          young
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old", header=TRUE)
```

Last, I have data frame that includes only participants from the CG (again in long format). This data frame does not include the age group variable.

```
df_3 <- read.table(text="
        ID            age_T1
        823516        16      
        823516        16      
        823516        16      
        823516        16      
        823516        16      
        823516        16
        823516        16      
        823516        16      
        823516        16      
        823516        16
        855510        77
        855510        77
        855510        77
        855510        77
        855510        77
        855510        77
        855510        77
        820870        39        
        820870        39        
        820870        39        
        820870        39        
        800796        88  
        800796        88  
        800796        88  
        800796        88  
        800796        88  
        800796        88  
        800958        37        
        800958        37        
        800958        37        
        800958        37        
        800958        37        
        836587        18      
        836587        18", header=TRUE)
```

I would now like to have a data frame that includes both the participants from the EG and the CG (like rbind df_2 and df_3). But I would like to insert the value on age_group to the CG participants that corresponds to the value the corresponding matched person from the EG has. For example, the person with the ID 836587 (CG) should receive the same value on age_group as 801208 (EG), because these two participants are a matched pair (according to df_1).

**This is how the final data set should look like:**

```
df_final <- read.table(text="
        ID            age_T1      age_group
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young        
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800289        18          young
        800674        40          middle
        800674        40          middle
        800674        40          middle
        800674        40          middle
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        811434        85          old
        838623        36          middle
        838623        36          middle
        838623        36          middle
        838623        36          middle
        838623        36          middle
        801208        21          young
        801208        21          young
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        801299        77          old
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        823516        16          young
        855510        77          old
        855510        77          old
        855510        77          old
        855510        77          old
        855510        77          old
        855510        77          old
        855510        77          old
        820870        39          middle
        820870        39          middle
        820870        39          middle
        820870        39          middle
        800796        88          old
        800796        88          old
        800796        88          old
        800796        88          old
        800796        88          old
        800796        88          old
        800958        37          middle
        800958        37          middle
        800958        37          middle
        800958        37          middle
        800958        37          middle
        836587        18          young
        836587        18          young", header=TRUE)
```

Do you have an idea how to do this? Any help or advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: How many rows would the final output have? Do you mean to have something like `merge(merge(df_2, df_1, by.x = "ID", by.y = "ID_EG"), df_3, by.x = "ID_CG", by.y = "ID")` ?

Comment: @RonakShah: Thanks for your question. Please see above how I need the final data frame to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing an easy way to do this but here is one way using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df_3 %>%
   mutate(age_group = NA_character_) %>%
   bind_rows(df_2 %>% mutate(age_group = as.character(age_group))) %>%
   left_join(df_1, by = c("ID" = "ID_EG")) %>%
   mutate(age_group = ifelse(is.na(age_group),age_group[match(ID, ID_CG)], age_group)) %>%
   select(-ID_CG)
```

Here we first add an empty column `age_group` in `df_3` and bind the rows with `df_2`. We then do a `left_join` with `df_1` by `"ID_EG"` and replace the `NA` values of "CG" in `age_group` with the corresponding "EG" value/